# Bootstrap: set select value in parent window from modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I have a SELECT menu in a form, is it possible to set its value by clicking a link in a Bootstrap modal?

Clicking the link would need to do two things:

1. Set the value in the SELECT menu in the parent window
2. Close the modal window (I can do that bit okay with this in the `a` tag: `onclick="$('#modalBackgrounds').modal('hide')"`

This is a simple mock up:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- form -->

<form>
  <select name="this" id="this" class='form-control'>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Orange</option>
    <option value="3">Yellow</option>
    <option value="4">Green</option>
    <option value="5">Blue</option>
  </select>
</form>

<!-- launch modal -->

<hr />
<p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBackgrounds">Launch Modal</a></p>

<!-- modal -->

<!-- Modal Backgrounds -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalBackgrounds" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabelFonts" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h1 class="modal-title">Backgrounds...</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive z-depth-1-half" style="height:400px;">
          <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#modalBackgrounds').modal('hide')">Red</a></p>
          <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#modalBackgrounds').modal('hide')">Orange</a></p>
          <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#modalBackgrounds').modal('hide')">Yellow</a></p>
          <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#modalBackgrounds').modal('hide')">Blue</a></p>
          <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#modalBackgrounds').modal('hide')">Green</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How can I set the value of the SELECT element with an ID / Name of `this` by clicking a link in the modal window, while also being able to close the modal window once the relevant link has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `data` attribute from modal to parent window and set the value of the select box. Also, no need to call `onclick="$('#modalBackgrounds').modal('hide')"` for each click, just use `data-dismiss="modal"`.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="embed-responsive z-depth-1-half" style="height:400px;">
        <p><a href="#" data-value="1" data-dismiss="modal">Red</a></p>
        <p><a href="#" data-value="2" data-dismiss="modal">Orange</a></p>
        <p><a href="#" data-value="3" data-dismiss="modal">Yellow</a></p>
        <p><a href="#" data-value="4" data-dismiss="modal">Blue</a></p>
        <p><a href="#" data-value="5" data-dismiss="modal">Green</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add following script:

```
<script>
    $('.modal-body a').click(function() {
        var value = $(this).data('value');
        $('select#this').val(value)
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vatsal Khanna - that works! However, I completely forgot that the content in the modal window between the `<div class="embed-responsive z-depth-1-half" style="height:400px;">` tags is held within an iframe. Is there any way the code can work if the HTML links are within an iframe. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do this by changing `$('select#this').val(value)` to  `window.parent.$('select#this').val(value)` in script

Comment: Hi @4532066 - If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This will be useful to anybody else in the community.

Comment: Hi Vatsal Khanna - sorry for the delayed reply. I did pick up your reply about the iframe amendment, and thank you for your advice. I couldn't get it to work though, I am not sure why. I tried putting the jQuery script on the parent page which the modal is called from, and also inside the external page which is included in the iframe SRC, but neither worked, and I couldn't figure out why. Also, when `data-dismiss="modal"` was included in the link that's inside the SRC page included in the iframe, the modal did not close either. Sorry, but thanks.

Comment: Did you try changing the call to hyperlinks? I believe `.modal-body a` won't work there. You may need to change it to `$('a').click(function(){ });`